# How to change Text color with Get in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

How can i change my Texts color immedietly

```
TextStyle get headingStyle {

  return GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      color:Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black);
}
```

color changes when i hot reloud but doesn't change when i clicked the button(button changes isDarkMode )

Comment: where is your implementation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try put the Obx.
It's create an observable in your code

```
TextStyle get headingStyle {

  return Obx(() => GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      color:Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black));
}
```

Comment: I'm returning TextStyle how can i return Obx 
I call this function for my text's style
'Text("example" style:headingStyle)'
And GoogleFonts is not a Widget i could not understand how can i use Obx.

Comment: U need put the Obx in someplace. And put and update(); too. But the Obx only Works n directlly getx obs variable